# Why does inline-block does not make div inline?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I wanted to make an inline div using inline-block, but it doesn't work and either turns it turns one of the two divs below and the other above

```css
#div-on-the-left {
  background-color: #464886;
  width: 200px;
  height: 600px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 10px double #2c2d54;
  margin: 5px;
}

#big-div-on-the-right {
  background-color: #AAABB8;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div-on-the-left">
  <!--Some html-->
</div>
<div id="big-div-on-the-right">
  <!--Some html-->
</div>
```

I also tried giving `#div-on-the-left` `inline-block` too, that brought `#big-div-on-the-right` above, but left a gap where `#div-on-the-left` was supposed to be and brought `#div-on-the-left` to the bottom, why is this happening?

Comment: what are you actually trying to achieve as final result? It seems to me, that you would be better off with the sue of flexbox or css-grid.

Answer (score 1):

YOu would be way better off using a grid or flexboxes. In this case flexboxes would be "easier" and "shorter". You main issue is, that both div-boxes have a different height. The left div-box have a height of `600px + (2x20px) = 640px` because of the double border. the right div-box have a height of only 600px causing different line height and therefor will cause a line-break. Next, the minimum-width has to be set large enough to allow both boxes to be displayed next to each other.

In the snippet below, I wrapped both boxes inside a wrapper with a minimum width high enough to let them be displayed next to each other. Then I changed them to `display: flex;`.

The height for the right box was set to 640px becaue of the border mentioned above.

```css
.wrapper {
  min-width: 850px;
  display: flex;
}

#div-on-the-left {
  background-color: #464886;
  width: 200px;
  height: 600px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 10px double #2c2d54;
  margin: 5px;
}

#big-div-on-the-right {
  background-color: #AAABB8;
  width: 600px;
  height: 640px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="div-on-the-left">
    <!--Some html-->
  </div>
  <div id="big-div-on-the-right">
    <!--Some html-->
  </div>
</div>
```